# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException when sorting array

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, object

I just want to sort the array of numbers by the sort method. But unfortunately it throws an error:

`java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException:10 at Search.sort(Search.java:30) at Search.main(Search.java:67)`

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Search {

  public Search() {
    System.out.println("inside a constructer");
  }

  public int[] sort(int x[]) {

    for (int i = 0; i < x.length - 1; i++)
      for (int j = 1; j < x.length; j++) {
        int temp;

        if (x[i] > x[j]) {
          temp = x[i];
          x[i] = x[j];
          x[j] = x[i];

        }

      }
    return x;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    // System.out.println("fgdg"+num);

    int num[] = new int[10];

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Eneter the 10 integers:");

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      System.out.println("Enter the " + (i + 1) + " number:");
      num[i] = sc.nextInt();
    }

    System.out.println("before sorting:");
    for (int m = 0; m <= num.length; m++)
      System.out.println(num[m]);

    Search obj = new Search();
    int x1[] = obj.sort(num);

    System.out.println("sorted:");

    for (int k = 0; k <= x1.length; k++)
      System.out.println(x1[k]);
  }
}
```

Comment: hey buddy itz not a  duplicate question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int num[] = new int[10]
```

means that your array has 10 elements(length = 10), indexes from 0 - 9.

change the for loop in the method to

```
for (int i=0;i<x.length;i++)
    for(int j=i+1;j<x.length;j++)
```

!!Change every loop that goes to

```
<= array.length
```

into

```
< array.length
```

since the last element of an array is at index array.length - 1.

You also have a mistake where you change the values of x[i] and x[j] in the sort function. It should be:

```
 if (x[i] > x[j]) {
      temp = x[i];
      x[i] = x[j];
      x[j] = temp;

    }
```

Your j loop in the sort method has to start from i + 1, not from 1.

Comment: i have made certain changes again doesnt work..

Comment: also change the before/after sorted loops in main

Comment: @Rameez I have just run your code and edited my answer, now you should manage to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

Change your for condition to this :

```
for (int i=0;i<x.length;i++)
    for(int j=1;j<x.length;j++){
       //your code
    }
}
```

What your code does : It checks every number in array starting from index 0 to size of array.

Lets say you have `array of 10 numbers`. Then size of array will be `10`. And you are iterating `from 0 to 10`. But numbers are stored in index position `0 to 9`. So it will thrown an exception when it try to fetch 10th element from array.

Comment: this doesnt work... i think there is a problem in last line obj.sort(num)

Answer (score 1):

Array indexes are zero-based.
Change

```
for (int i=0;i<=x.length;i++)
    for(int j=1;j<=x.length;j++)
```

to

```
for (int i=0;i<x.length;i++)
    for(int j=i;j<x.length;j++)
```

**UPDATE:**

Two more places. Change `<=` to `<`

```
for (int m = 0; m <= num.length; m++)
        System.out.println(num[m]);
```

and

```
for (int k = 0; k <= x1.length; k++)
        System.out.println(x1[k]);
```

Comment: changed it ... but not working again...plz check the code again as i have made some changes

Comment: BTW, your `temp` variable is assigned but not used. It's a bug.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i=0;i<=x.length;i++)
        for(int j=1;j<=x.length;j++)
    {
        int temp=0;

        if(x[i]>x[j])
        {
            temp=x[i];
            x[i]=x[j];
            x[j]=x[i];

        }


    }
```

Should be

```
for (int i=0;i<x.length;i++)
        for(int j=1;j<x.length;j++)
    {
        int temp=0;

        if(x[i]>x[j])
        {
            temp=x[i];
            x[i]=x[j];
            x[j]=temp;

        }


    }
```

You are exceeding the size of array!

Answer (score 0):

change your for loop to this code:

```
for (int i=0;i<x.length;i++)
    for(int j=i;j<x.length;j++)
```